# PowerShell Script for updating a visual studio .vsxproj file

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a small problem. I want to search a directory ,lets say D:\ . I want to find the files with the extention .vsxproj. Then I can do 2 things.
 1. Access a node called project properties and change a single word amongst a string.
 2. Or, just replace the word from the entire file without searching specific node. This is easier and would serve my purpose. 
Now for the actual code. I have tried the following.

```
    (Get-Content D:\data123.xml) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "Wow32", "Wow3232" } |
    Set-Content D:\data123.xml
```

This works for a single file if I know the name. But i have more than a hundred file.So I try something like this.I go to my D drive and do this:

```
    $configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.vsxproj -rec
    foreach ($file in $configFiles)
    {
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "Wow32", "Wow3232" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
    }
```

Please let me know how can I recurse over several file and change this one word. I have searched and looked at quite a few answers.None of them actually solves my problem. Please help.

Comment: What happens when you execute the code that you have here?

Comment: the first one works. But I need to have the names of all the files and change it manually. Second one does nothing apparently . Although I get no errors !! @alroc

Comment: Your second example works for me. Are you sure that `Get-ChildItem` returns any files?

Comment: I have files .So why shoudnt it return ?? I am a bit confused here !!

Comment: What I found is that it works with the .xml extention but fails when the files are .vsxproj . Any ideas??

P.S Sorry the correct extention was .vcxproj . The code workds  :)